# Grails How to work with GORM when it comes to composition (To HasMany or to not)

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm

So I have an object Person let's say, with the following fields (for simplicity)

```
class Person{
    String name
    List<Address> addressList
}

class Address{
    String streetNo
}
```

This would be the way to go usually, but now that im working with grails I thought it should be the following:

```
class Person{
    String name
    List addresses
    static hasMany = [addresses: Address]    
}

class Address{
    String streetNo
    static belongsTo = Person
}
```

I'm receiving the data from an HTTP call and im trying to save it:

```
    def persons = response.getAt("response").getAt("persons").collect()
    persons.forEach({ current ->
        def person = new Person(current)
        person.save()
    })
```

The parsing is working properly as when I check the person object before saving it, I can see the address being added correctly (at first NOT saved and without an ID but after the save, an ID is added)

Now when I want to fetch all persons, I do a basic

```
    respond Person.list()
```

I get all the details correct but the address I get only the address IDs so for example:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: foo,
    addresses:[
    {id:1},{id:2}    
    ]
}
```

But what I want here is the actual address object not its id! 
Also I noticed that after retrieving the Person list a couple of times the addresses list gets empty and I end up with addresses:[]

I tried to remove the hasMany and go back to the list but it didn't work either, I went through the official documentation but nothing points out more than what I already tried and/or mentioned

Comment: what is Grails version? how long the `addresses` list can be? What DB are you using?

Comment: Im using in memory H2 (by default) and I believe I have the newest Grails version (4+). Let's say each person can have up.to 5 addresses and each address has 3-4 properties. (I don't mind not having an actual table for addresses as I tried having it embedded but that didn't work either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to render your `hasMany` refs:

1. turn lazy-loading for `addresses` off:

   ```
   class Person{
       String name
       List addresses
       static hasMany = [addresses: Address]    
       static mapping = {
           addresses lazy: false
       }
   }
   ```

   as you rather want the `addresses` to behave as `embedded` objects.
2. You can resolve each `address` in a `person` by explicitly call it's props:

   ```
   def list = Person.list()
   list*.addresses*.streetNo
   respond list
   ```
3. use Jackson-annotations

   ```
   @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY) // either for the class
   class Person{
       String name

       @JsonProperty // or for each prop
       List addresses
       static hasMany = [addresses: Address]    
   }
   ```

UPDATE

4. If you use mongo, you can use `embedded` to its full strength:

   ```
   class Person{
       String name
       List<Address> addresses    
       static embedded = [ 'addresses' ]
   }

   class Address{
       String streetNo
   }
   ```

Comment: I switched to mongo as I felt it's a bit easier to deal with, I tried the first and the third solution but with no luck, I still get the Id of the address rather than the object itself

Comment: Also regarding point 2, it's failing to see the props of addresses for some reason

Comment: Im assuming that in case of number 4, I dont need to have Address in a different table, right?

Comment: yepp. all addresses go as an array of sub-documents inside the `Person` document

Comment: I'm facing an issue with mongo while trying #4 (readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is INT64) will try to solve it and re try again

Comment: as I thought, after cleaning my mongo collections everything worked out! thanks for the help, couldn't find this anywhere else after 2 days of googling!
Edit: yeah just saw your comment and yes it was the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214079/discussion-between-bleh10-and-injecteer).

Answer (score 0):

in Person try to add

static mapping { fetch: 'join' }